# What is the backend web framework role with AngularJS on the frontend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, client-side, server-side

Choosing the "right" web framework is quite challenging task, at least in Java we have a lot of them. But looking at JavaScript frameworks like AngularJS I doubt if we really need something heavy at server. Usually web framework is responsible for routing, templating, building pretty URLs and some other stuff. With AngularJS we can move all these responsibilities to client side. Then the backend becomes nothing more than REST listener and data validator. A thin layer between your application logic and client view. So why do we need web frameworks now if all we want is a REST listener?

At the moment I found two points which must be handled by server side: authentication/authorization and things requiring 'pushing' like Comet. Are these criterias enough to choose the "right" framework?

Comment: It highly depends on application

Comment: Could you clarify? What kind of applications cannot (or harder) be implemented without real web framework on backend?

Comment: it's the opposite: my point that it depends on the application: "With AngularJS we can move all these responsibilities to client side". Not every application would allow to move routing to the client side. I don't mention templating since you still need one on the server. And you still need pretty urls builder, since urls are used not only in the client browser, but, for example, are sent in emails.

Comment: You do not need templating on the server any more if you're using AngularJS. That's the end of server side templating for those developers. As for pretty URLs, what of that has to be done server side. Angular is perfectly happy with a URL that looks like this: "somesite/jokes#!/why-did-the-chicken". It would simply turn around and ask the server for the joke passing the string as the identifier instead of some arbitrary number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you one more capability that I've seen require back-end server support. It's those pages which generate a file. For example, they get a file from a third party and then hand it to the client as though they produced it directly, or they are generating a JPEG/PNG/GIF image on the fly, or perhaps a CSV/XLS dump of data. There may be ways to generate those on the fly from the front end and make them available for download, but sometimes the back-end is just easier for those.

Other than that, your assessment is 100% correct. You literally need *less* server for apps built with AngularJS than was needed with the previous request/response model of ASP/JSP/PHP/etc.

However, just because you need less doesn't mean you need nothing. Issues like data caching and how user sessions are handled can still come up even for smaller servers as you scale. But it has definitely opened things up for tech like Node.js to be considered that I would not have given much thought to a few years back.